# How to add the languages in the app store listing - We are not able to see more languages on iTunes Page of our Game

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

For Ex:

[image: This is how it is shown on App Store Page Listing]
We have been trying yo figure out various ways to show our languages (localized) listing on the store page - not able to get any source to list the languages on Apple App Store.

Please help.

Thanks,
Sid.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for days.. did y'all ever have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your App Store entry (iTunes page) to display more than one localisation you need to add localised assets to iTunes connect. This is separate to the app's localisations you would add within Xcode.

Take a look at Apple Devloper Docs - [Displaying on the Store in More Than One Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html)

It covers things like:

1. Adding New Languages
2. Viewing and Editing Metadata for Supported Languages
3. Changing the Primary Language

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have a practice of uploading the localization assets to iTunes Connect i.e. we have added all the localized languages in developers tab with English as our Primary language. But, our concern here was to display the languages we have accommodated in our game to appear on the Store listing. Ex: This is what we see in store listing on the left corner of our regular app/game pages on store. Ex: Free Category: Games Updated: 25 October 2016 Version: 8.551.18 Size: 84.6 MB """""Languages: English, Japanese, Korean, Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese""""""